# How to display strings in an array one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build something like a Countdown, but not a countdown. I am actually sill learning and would appreciate any direction you can point me to.

I managed to accomplish this working code:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }

    console.log(html);

    // Split every word and separate them by a comma
    var split = html.split(" ");
    console.log(split);
    confirm(split);
}
```

What it does is, that it gets a selected/highlighted Numbers and presents them to the reader. But I actually want to do stuff with it first, with the highlighted Numbers.

I want them to be displayed in a new DIV one after the other. Let say I highlight 1 to 10 and after I click the button, a Div Tag should show up with the Number 1, after that the Number 2 and so on, Until I reached the Number 10.

Any help? Unfortunately my jsfidle isn't working and I don't know why.
Thank you in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/X9aPj/

EDIT: I figured out by adding:

```
    var array = split;
    console.log(array);
```

That I can put the seleciton into an array. Now I have to figure out how to loop them to be displayed one after another in a separate new div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X9aPj/3/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I actually meant with "one after another", that it should be like a counter, or countdown. The one array disappears where the next one appears. Now they are just beneath each other. Nonetheless I am very grateful for your contribution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `setTimeout` in a loop to output the array. [Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/X9aPj/5/)

```
var out = document.getElementById('out');
function outputNext() {
    out.innerHTML = split.pop();
    if (split.length) {
        setTimeout(outputNext, 1000);
    }
}
outputNext();
```

Comment: Thank you Kavun,
That was the answer I was looking for. Any Idea how to make the count go from left to right, instead of right to left?

Comment: // Reverse the Array
    var splitreversed = split.reverse();
    console.log(splitreversed);